# How to call web service periodically and fill data to listview

Tags: android, listview, background-process, android-adapter

I have list View which is filled from web service and i have to check continuously  for any data change on server and want to reflect on list view.Please help me.

Comment: have you tried some thing...??

Comment: i tried alaram Manager but not get satisfectory result

Comment: First share your working.

The way you want to get updated your listview as server data is updated then you have to implement GCM which will send a notification to the device and the device will refresh its data according to the server